# EJS not loading CSS file

Tags: css, node.js, express, ejs

Im using EJS and trying to style with CSS, but CSS is not loading. I have other project structured the same way and it loads correctly.
Here there are some screenshots and code from the project.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const ejsMate = require('ejs-mate');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/umarket', { 
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    // useCreateIndex: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
    // useFindAndModify: false 
})
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Database Connected")
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log("Ups... Error!");
        console.log(err);
    }) 

const path = require('path');

app.engine('ejs', ejsMate);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));


app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));




app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('home');     // **it is not loading CSS here.**
});


app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Running - Port: 3000');
})
```

I have my **home.ejs** file inside **/views/home.ejs**
[image]

and my **home.css** **file inside /public/stylesheets/home.css**

Also my ***home.ejs*** code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Umarket</title>
    <!-- <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/stylesheets/home.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="k">asda</h1>
    




    <!-- <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-eMNCOe7tC1doHpGoWe/6oMVemdAVTMs2xqW4mwXrXsW0L84Iytr2wi5v2QjrP/xp" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cn7l7gDp0eyniUwwAZgrzD06kc/tftFf19TOAs2zVinnD/C7E91j9yyk5//jjpt/" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: my home.css file just contains
`.k {font-size: 30px;}`  but nothing updates.

Comment: You don't have any routes that would serve the CSS file.  Probably you need a route using `express.static()` that points to the path your using for the CSS file .  Nodejs does not serve any files by itself.

Comment: Hi!
So how can I add them? What am I missing then?

Comment: Yeah thank you, it was that, I was missing `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))` !!! What a noob!

Answer (score 0):

Please, remove `public` from your path `href="/public/stylesheets/home.css"`.

It should be `href="/stylesheets/home.css"`

Also, you need to turn serving static files from the public

```
app.use(express.static("public"));
```

Comment: make it a static file first

Comment: Yes it was that, I was missing `app.use(express.static("public"));`
Thank you for your time!